# Partially mock React module with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, babel-jest

I'm trying to mock only one function in imported React module, keep the rest of the module unmocked and do this at top level for all tests.

I'm using fresh create-react-app project with a single test to observe the problem.

Steps to reproduce:

- `create-react-app test`
- use provided `src/App.test.js` as the only test file
- `npm run test`

*App.test.js*

```
jest.mock('react', () => {
  jest.dontMock('react');

  const React = require('react');
  const lazy = jest.fn();

  return {
    ...React,
    lazy
  };
});

import * as React from 'react';
const React2 = require('react');

it('should partially mock React module', async () => {
  expect(jest.isMockFunction(React.lazy)).toBe(true); // passes
  expect(jest.isMockFunction(React2.lazy)).toBe(true); // fails
  expect(jest.isMockFunction(require('react').lazy)).toBe(true); // fails
  expect(jest.isMockFunction((await import('react')).lazy)).toBe(true); // fails
});
```

The problem here seems to be `jest.dontMock` as it prevents `require` and dynamic `import` from being mocked, but it remains unclear why it was possible to mock static `import` this way, as it uses `require` any way. Here's transpiled file:

```
"use strict";

jest.mock('react', () => {
  jest.dontMock('react');

  const React = require('react');

  const lazy = jest.fn();
  return (0, _objectSpread2.default)({}, React, {
    lazy
  });
});

var _interopRequireWildcard3 = require("...\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard");

var _interopRequireDefault = require("...\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _interopRequireWildcard2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("...\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard"));

var _objectSpread2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("...\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime/helpers/objectSpread"));

var React = _interopRequireWildcard3(require("react"));

const React2 = require('react');
...
```

This may have something to do with create-react-app Jest+Babel setup because I was unable to make `jest.dontMock` work incorrectly with vanilla Jest and `require`.

Why is static `React` import mocked but `React2` and the rest aren't? What exactly is going on inside?

How can `jest.dontMock` current behaviour be fixed to partially mock a module at top level?

Comment: I think `require.requireActual` should do the trick as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-265074320). Also `jest.dontMock('react')` is not needed with this. I don't know why `dontMock` is behaving differently for import vs require - it should prevent mocking in both cases.

Comment: @AWolf I knew about requireActual but totally forgot about it and somehow overlooked it in the issue you linked. Indeed, that's the solution, thank you. Consider providing this fix as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Default Imports:

A simple solution would be to mock `React.lazy` in the `setupTest.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.spyOn(React.lazy);
```

Any subsequent `require/imports` of `react` will be partially mocked for each test file.

**Working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-lazy-mocked (I don't use the `create-react-app`, but `jest` can be set up the same way as I have it)

Installation:

- `git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/react-lazy-mocked.git`
- `cd react-lazy-mocked`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn test`

---

**root/__tests__/root.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../index.js';

const React2 = require('react');

describe('App', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);

  it('renders without errors', () => {
    const homeComponent = wrapper.find('.app');
    expect(homeComponent).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should partially mock React module', async () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(await require('react').lazy)).toBe(true); // eslint-disable-line global-require
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React)).toBe(false);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React.lazy)).toBe(true);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React2)).toBe(false);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React2.lazy)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should no longer be partially mocked within the test file', () => {
    React.lazy.mockRestore();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React.lazy)).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

**pages/Home/__tests__/Home.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../index.js';

describe('Home', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);

  it('renders without errors', () => {
    const homeComponent = wrapper.find('.app');
    expect(homeComponent).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should partially mock React module', async () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React.lazy)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

---

### Named Imports:

**Working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/named-react-lazy-mocked

Installation:

- `git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/named-react-lazy-mocked.git`
- `cd named-react-lazy-mocked`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn test`

**utils/__mocks__/react.js**

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...require.requireActual('react'),
  lazy: jest.fn(),
}));
module.exports = require.requireMock('react');
```

**utils/setup/setupTest.js** (optionally, you can add the mocked `react` file as a `global` jest function so you won't have to write `import * as React from 'react'` for every test):

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
// import React from '../__mocks__/react';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// global.React = React;
```

**root/__tests__/root.test.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import App from '../index.js';

const React2 = require('react');

describe('App', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);

  it('renders without errors', () => {
    const homeComponent = wrapper.find('.app');
    expect(homeComponent).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should partially mock React module', async () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(await require('react').lazy)).toBe(true); // eslint-disable-line global-require
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React)).toBe(false);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React.lazy)).toBe(true);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React2)).toBe(false);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(React2.lazy)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Sadly, this won't work for my case because the problem is to mock named imports. Things could be simpler for default `import React from 'react'` but I'm not using it. React imports are most often used as `import React, { lazy } from 'react'`, where `React` default export is used only by Babel/TS to provide `React.createElement` for JSX transform.

Comment: Do you mean something like `import * as React from 'react'; React.lazy = jest.fn()`? This won't work due to how Babel's ES module interop works for `*`.

Comment: Figured it out for named exports. Updated the answer to include both.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I'm doing this now.